# Logic Apps variable in replace expression

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a Logic Apps instance with a variable AddedPoKey set out of parsed JSON

```
                            "Set_PO_Key_variable_": {
                            "inputs": {
                                "name": "AddedPoKey",
                                "value": "@{body('Parse_JSON')?['poKey']}"
                            },
                            "runAfter": {
                                "Parse_JSON": [
                                    "Succeeded"
                                ]
                            },
                            "type": "SetVariable"
                        },
```

I want to use the value to set the Id in a RESTful API collection resource. I have not been able to get it to work, though I am sure it should. I am possible not finding the best MS documentation on this and if any could be pointed out to me, I would appreciate it. I have tried:

```
                            "Set_Po_Lin_Add_url_": {
                            "inputs": {
                                "name": "CreatePoLineResourceUrl",
                                "value": "@{replace('https://api.plex.com/EDI/sales-orders/{PoKey}/lines','{PoKey}',triggerBody()['AddedPoKey'])}"
                            },
                            "runAfter": {
                                "Set_PO_Key_variable_": [
                                    "Succeeded"
                                ]
                            },
                            "type": "SetVariable"
                        }
```

Which results in InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Set_Po_Lin_Add_url_' inputs at line '1' and column '2459': 'The template language expression 'replace('https://api.plex.com/EDI/sales-orders/{PoKey}/lines','{PoKey}',triggerBody()['AddedPoKey'])' cannot be evaluated because property 'AddedPoKey' doesn't exist, available properties are 'ContentData, ContentType, ContentTransferEncoding, Properties, MessageId, To, ReplyTo, ReplyToSessionId, Label, ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc, SessionId, CorrelationId, SequenceNumber, LockToken, TimeToLive'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions for usage details.'.

Answer (score 1):

and then

```
"@{replace('https://api.plex.com/EDI/sales-orders/{PoKey}/lines','{PoKey}',variables('AddedPoKey')}"
```

which **works**.

Note that https://aka.ms/logicexpressions had been my main references, but does not even have the word "variable" on the page at this time.

Comment: Are you writing this in the code view? Have you tried using the expression editor in the designer, which will allow you to select variables and tokens while building an expression.

Comment: In my experience, using Edge and Firefox, the expression editor and designer falls down at the third nesting of conditionals. That drove me to the code view.

Comment: what is the purpose of the curley brakcets?

Comment: I am just using them to set off the query parameter being replaces with a value at run time. The braces are not required.